# "upstream" error from nginx ... can't figure it out

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, uwsgi

I am getting this error when trying to start nginx:

/$ sudo nginx -t

"nginx: [emerg] "upstream" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/catalog_nginx.conf:4"

I have this file "catalog_nginx.conf" located in the root of my app:

```
# catalog_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    #server unix:///home/ec2-user/catalog/catalog.sock; # production
    server 127.0.0.1:8001; # testing
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    listen  8000;
    server_name 54.redacted; 
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /home/ec2-user/catalog/media/;  # media files
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/ec2-user/catalog/static/; # static files
    }

    # all non-media requests
    location / {
    uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/ec2-user/catalog/uwsgi_params; 
    }
}
```

In the 'nginx.conf' file from /etc/nginx/ I have the following under http{}

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
```

I have symlinked the two files.

Thoughts?

Comment: Maybe showing the underlying part of the file would be useful.

Comment: Does this help: http://serverfault.com/questions/654957/nginx-emerg-server-directive-is-not-allowed-here-in-etc-nginx-nginx-conf7